# Stateful Session Bean

Tags: java

Estoy realizando prácticas de JEE, el tema que estoy tratando son los Bean con y sin estado, tengo el siguiente proyecto que es mi Bean con estado y tengo el código que es mi cliente para ese bean:https://github.com/RaizrNs3/Statefull-Bean-Excercise.

Lo que hacía en el ejercicio era "deployar" el proyecto con el Bean, luego en la consola de Glassfish copiar el JNDI que se generaba y agregarlo al cliente; durante la sesión me funcionó correctamente pero al tratar de probar en otra máquina al correr el cliente se produce la excepción "NoInitialContextException", el JNDI que se genera es el siguiente:

> *java:global/EJBPractica02/RegistraUsuarioBean!mx.unam.dgtic.interfaz.RegistraUsuarioRemote*

que coincide correctamente con la estructura del proyecto sin embargo sigue sin funcionar. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea del por qué está pasando esto?